# How wavy is an array?

Tags: code-golf, math

A *wave* of power \$k\$ is an infinite array that looks like \$1,2,\dots,k,k-1,\dots,1,\dots,k,\dots,1,\dots\$, and so on.
For example, a wave of power 3 starts with \$1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,1,...\$, and repeats indefinitely. A wave of power 1 is an infinite array of ones. They happen to be beautifully expressed as $$w_k[t] = k - |(t - 1)\bmod(2k - 2) - k + 1|\text{, 1-indexed}$$

In this challenge, all waves are trimmed to their first \$n\$ elements, where \$n\$ is the length of the input array.

A *decomposition of an array into waves* is an array of coefficients of length \$n\$ such that the original array equals the sum of the waves multiplied by their corresponding coefficients. Formally, if the original array is \$A\$, the decomposition is an array \$B\$  such that for any \$i\$  (\$1 \le i \le n\$) the following equality holds:
$$A[i] = \sum_{j=1}^\infty B[j] \cdot w_j[i]\text{, 1-indexed}$$

The *waviness* of an array is the index of the last non-zero value in its decomposition into waves.

The task is, given a positive integer array of length \$n\$, to calculate its waviness. Note that the decomposition can still include non-integer and negative numbers.

### Test cases

All test cases below are 1-indexed. Your solution may use 0-indexing instead.

```
[1, 1, 1] -> 1                 (decomposition: [1, 0, 0])
[1, 2, 1] -> 2                 (decomposition: [0, 1, 0])
[1, 2, 3] -> 3                 (decomposition: [0, 0, 1])
[1, 1, 2] -> 3                 (decomposition: [1, -0.5, 0.5])
[1, 3, 3, 3, 1] -> 3           (decomposition: [-1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
[1, 2, 2, 4] -> 4              (decomposition: [0, 0.5, -0.5, 1]
[4, 6, 9, 1, 4, 3, 5] -> 7     (decomposition: [2, -0.5, 5, -5, 6.5, -1, -3]
[4, 6, 9, 1, 4, 3, 5, 7] -> 8  (decomposition: [2, -0.5, 5, -5, 6.5, -1, -10.5, 7.5])
```

This is tagged [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) <sup>an uncommon justification</sup>, so the shortest answer wins.

Comment: [Deleted sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18170/36445)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>34</s></sup> <sup><s>33</s></sup> 27 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each)

```apl
⊢{⊢/⍋0≠⍺⌹⍉↑(1+⍵⍴⍳,⊢-⍳)¨⍳⍵}≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OB5KOuRdVArP@ot9vgUeeCR727HvXsfNTb@ahtooah9qPerY96tzzq3awDVKMLpDUPrQCSQOHaR52LQEYBjUhXMOSCs0AQiWeExjNGUWmExDMGQ1TVRgomcL6JgpmCJVDUBKjKFLuogjlUXMMQYhkYmiiYK1ho6hr@BwA)

Lots of golfing thanks to [ngn](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52223665#52223665).

#### How it works

```apl
g←⊢{⊢/⍋0≠⍺⌹⍉↑(1+⍵⍴⍳,⊢-⍳)¨⍳⍵}≢  Accept a vector V of length N
  ⊢{                       }≢  Call the inner function with ⍺=V, ⍵=N
                         ⍳⍵    Make 0..N-1
             (    ⍳,⊢-⍳)¨      For each i of above, make 0..i-1,i..1 and
              1+⍵⍴               repeat/truncate to length N and +1
         ⍺⌹⍉↑                  Reform above as matrix and solve equations
       0≠                      Test nonzero on each item (nonzero→1, zero→0)
    ⊢/⍋                        Find the last index of 1
```

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>34</s></sup> 33 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each)

```apl
⍴-0(⊥⍨=)⊢⌹∘⍉∘↑1+⍴⍴¨(⊢,1+⌽)∘⍳¨∘⍳∘⍴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDBSsNAEIbP3aeYY5Ya2E2i1UMewJPPUBD20kavIr0GWxpRRPDipSDk5qH14MFLHmVeJP67q6GJtrUyMLP/8M83ww4vR@H51XB0YWqjOL@7Fr0MhYsVF2@iN3bvKef3GVpVGfBscaA5f6hebeb5h@SbJy6WVYmUYTjk2QsXpUoxz/P3sZgIo3@Cu759lkwEF88UeJQMyZNIpeRZKFMCrbE4Km3BYmJJX6dZtsGlZBshqcDjYU0lVi2wILDXYhQrrMml7Qt8dXklhYn8T4Tf8FR2we6YHX/RZsYbmM7wP6rg28fTM3BVbf5A1/02v7@JW4MLniENoUWjbKypqKPiljNaU7GLtjuipNEJHdEJuglch793aSAC7de4SGhAx7L@BA)

Uses `⎕IO←0` and an alternative way to generate the matrix W.

```apl
g←⍴-0(⊥⍨=)⊢⌹∘⍉∘↑1+⍴⍴¨(⊢,1+⌽)∘⍳¨∘⍳∘⍴  Accept a vector of length n
                                ⍳∘⍴  Make a vector 0..n-1
                     (⊢,1+⌽)∘⍳¨      For each k of above, chain 0..k-1 and k..1
                  ⍴⍴¨                  and repeat or truncate to length n
                                     The first row has 0 elements, repeat gives n zeros
                1+                   Increment all elements
  ⍴-0(⊥⍨=)⊢⌹∘⍉∘↑                     The rest is the same as the previous answer
```

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 34 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each)

```apl
⍴-0(⊥⍨=)⊢⌹∘⍉∘↑⍴⍴¨(⊢,1↓¯1↓⌽)∘⍳¨∘⍳∘⍴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDBSsNAEIbPnaeY4y64kKTR6iEPUyjspY29ivQa2tIVSxG89FIQcvPQevDgJY8yL5LOzmqNUSuWgZnM5J/vH7Y/HprBTX94bWsbUXF/C52cC7kduRfojOR7RsUy51FVKppvzmIqVtWzz7R40zR9JLetSk45LxuaP5Ero4z3afE6ggnY@Du4rfuPyQTIrVEFlDYYSBhlGFhcZsi0g0SoeATLG1t8P82zLV@KfmAwUgHP0kyz1YYNlL@WV9nCiyQdNwhV8k6DTcJLmA94pttgOeaPt2gya/sLUv6fBq3p7oGpFmMf8Nklra4LTWXS6LoSX9UJpoc@xQu84mnKqvOfp9gDJSYSKfbwUtd7)

A monadic train that accepts a numeric vector.

#### How it works

```apl
g←⍴-0(⊥⍨=)⊢⌹∘⍉∘↑⍴⍴¨(⊢,1↓¯1↓⌽)∘⍳¨∘⍳∘⍴  Accept a vector of length n
                                 ⍳∘⍴  Make a vector 1..n
                   (⊢,1↓¯1↓⌽)∘⍳¨      For each k of the above, generate one unit of wave of power k (1..k..2)
                ⍴⍴¨                   Repeat or truncate each row to length n (result is nested vector)
             ⍉∘↑                      Convert nested vector to matrix, and transpose it
          ⊢⌹                          Solve the linear equation
    0(⊥⍨=)                            Count trailing zeros
  ⍴-                                  Subtract from n
```

Basically, this solution uses the same W matrix as [Arnauld's submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194504/78410), solves the linear equation, and then finds the index of the last nonzero entry using the good old "count trailing ones" `⊥⍨`.

Comment: I know 33 is without it, but you might want to remove `g←` from the leading one.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>172 171</s>  169 bytes

The output is 0-indexed.

```javascript
a=>a.map((_,i)=>(D=m=>+m||m.reduce((s,[v],i)=>s+(i&1?-v:v)*D(m.map(([,...r])=>r).filter(_=>i--)),0))(a.map((v,y)=>a.map((_,x)=>x-i?x-~-Math.abs(y%(2*x)-x):v)))&&(j=i))|j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY5da4MwFIbv@ytyMzmnTdL50XUbxN70dr9ApGRWu4jWEp2kIPvrLnMrDFthC@9NOM/L8@aylXWi1alhx2qf9pnopQglL@UJYEcVihC2ohThouy6kut0/56kADWN2ni41gtQjrth7XOL8y2U382Ics51bO8aeaaKJtWwE6FiDJHeI8KPoaVn/KUz9mOY2hj2wV5k88blaw3nO/DmBplBq0B0HMiFQuzyPqmOdVWkvKgOkEHkUvKVGJGM33JJ3Nk17k3j3m3cn8D92c0x3j9w/5LRpAncGxJcCSwejPGAkgdKnoZJweBYXXoWX/8Bp2Q9NCz@2H8C)

#### How?

This is essentially an implementation of [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), except that the denominator is not computed.

Given the input vector of length \$n\$, we define \$W_n\$ as the matrix holding the waves, stored column-wise.

*Example:*

$$W_5=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
1&2&2&2&2\\
1&1&3&3&3\\
1&2&2&4&4\\
1&1&1&3&5\end{pmatrix}$$

We compute all values \$v_i=\det(M_i)\$ with \$0\le i<n\$, where \$M_i\$ is the matrix formed by replacing the \$i\$-th column of \$W_n\$ with the input vector.

*Example:*

For the 5<sup>th</sup> test case and \$i=3\$, this gives:

$$v_3=\det(M_3)=\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&\color{red}1&1\\
1&2&2&\color{red}3&2\\
1&1&3&\color{red}3&3\\
1&2&2&\color{red}3&4\\
1&1&1&\color{red}1&5\end{vmatrix}=0$$

We return the highest index \$j\$ such that \$v_j\neq0\$.

#### Commented

The helper function \$D\$ uses [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) to compute the determinant:

```javascript
D = m =>                     // m[] = matrix
  +m ||                      // if the matrix is a singleton, return it
  m.reduce((s, [v], i) =>    // otherwise, for each value v at (0, i):
    s                        //   take the previous sum s
    + (i & 1 ? -v : v)       //   based on the parity of i, add either v or -v
    * D(                     //   multiplied by the result of a recursive call:
      m.map(([, ...r]) => r) //     pass m[] with the 1st column removed
      .filter(_ => i--)      //     and the i-th row removed
    ),                       //   end of recursive call
    0                        //   start with sum = 0
  )                          // end of reduce()
```

The matrix \$M_i\$ is computed with:

```javascript
a.map((v, y) =>         // for each value v at position y in the input vector a[]:
  a.map((_, x) =>       //   for each value at position x in the input vector a[]:
    x - i ?             //     if this is not the i-th column:
      x -               //       compute the wave of power x+1 at position y:
      ~-Math.abs(       //         x - (|y mod (2*x) - x| - 1)
        y % (2 * x) - x //         (where y mod 0 is coerced to 0)
      )                 //
    :                   //     else:
      v                 //       append the value a[y] of the input vector
  )                     //   end of inner map()
)                       // end of outer map()
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 111 bytes

```
function w=f(A)
n=length(A)
W=ones(n,1)
for k=2:n
W(1:n,k)=k-abs(mod(0:n-1,2*k-2)-k+1)
end
w=max(find(W\A))
end
```

I'm new to this, do MATLAB answers have to be in a `function`, or can we assume `A` is set implicitly?

The code is straight-forward. The sum in the OP can be replaced with a simple matrix multiplication, `A = W*B`. The code computes `B = inv(W)*A` and finds the index of the last non-zero entry in `B`. `mod(x,0)` isn't well-defined, so the first row has to be set manually.